# How can I overcome problems with Dplyr grouping functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use the grouping function within dplyr in r. I'm working with the following data

| serial_number | entity | start | end | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | apple | 4 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | pear | 7 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | pear juice | 7 | 16 | 10 |
| 3 | juice | 12 | 16 | 5 |
| 3 | melon | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | guava | 43 | 47 | 5 |
| 5 | tomato | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 5 | juice | 8 | 12 | 5 |
| 5 | tomato juice | 1 | 12 | 12 |
| 6 | grapes | 9 | 14 | 6 |

For each serial number I am trying to extract the longest entity which starts or ends at the same point, I am expecting the following result:

| serial_number | entity | start | end | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | apple | 4 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | pear juice | 7 | 16 | 10 |
| 3 | melon | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | guava | 43 | 47 | 5 |
| 5 | tomato juice | 1 | 12 | 12 |
| 6 | grapes | 9 | 14 | 6 |

I am trying to group the data in dplyr and have tried the following to group by serial number and then start (will also need to do similar for end locations).

```
example_data <- data.frame(serial_number=c(1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6),
                           entity=c("banana","apple","pear","pear juice","juice","melon","guava","tomato","juice","tomato juice","grapes"),
                           start=c(1,4,7,7,12,1,43,1,8,1,9),
                           end=c(6,8,10,16,16,5,47,6,12,12,14),
                           length=c(6,5,4,10,5,5,5,6,5,12,6)
                           )
 

example_data <- dplyr::group_by(example_data, serial_number)
example_data <- dplyr::group_by(example_data, start)
results_test <- dplyr::filter(example_data, length==max(length))
```

However this yields the following, I have tried other things and I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of using the group_by function, particularly recursively (i.e. a group and then a further sub-group)

| serial_number | entity | start | end | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | apple | 4 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | pear juice | 7 | 16 | 10 |
| 3 | juice | 12 | 16 | 5 |
| 5 | guava | 43 | 47 | 5 |
| 5 | juice | 8 | 12 | 5 |
| 6 | tomato juice | 1 | 12 | 12 |
| 7 | grapes | 9 | 14 | 6 |

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: You may have overrided the first grouping `example_data %>% group_by(serial_number, start) %>% filter(length == max(length))` (when you apply group_by again) or use `.add = TRUE`

Comment: What does "longest entity which starts or ends at the same point" mean? If A starts where B starts, and B ends where C ends, are they all one group, even if A starts and ends different places than C?

Comment: You can't get to your desired output with simple group: a `serial_number` of 3, for instance, has three distinct `start` values, which means you should get all three with your filter. Regardless, as akrun said, each `group_by` _overrides_ the previous grouping ... **unless** you use `group_by(..., .add = TRUE)`, which is cumulative.

Comment: What logic are you using to result in two summary rows for serial_number 3? I wonder if this is partly a network problem to identify cliques which are linked through pairwise matches on either start or end point. That is beyond the normal use of dplyr, I think, and might be appropriate to bring in `igraph`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just that when we call the `group_by` multiple times, it overrides the grouping with the last call unless we call `.add = TRUE`.  Here, we don't need to do multiple group_by, as a single group_by can take more than one variable

```
library(dplyr)
 example_data %>%
  group_by(serial_number, grp = cumsum(start == 1)) %>% 
  slice_max(length) %>% 
  group_by(serial_number) %>% 
  arrange(start, desc(end), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(start)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
 # A tibble: 7 × 5
  serial_number entity       start   end length
          <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1             1 banana           1     6      6
2             2 apple            4     8      5
3             3 melon            1     5      5
4             3 pear juice       7    16     10
5             4 guava           43    47      5
6             5 tomato juice     1    12     12
7             6 grapes           9    14      6
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - this works exactly as I needed. And works well on the 'proper' data too. A key learning point for me - using group_by multiple times leads to problems. Code provided is also useful to look at the other dplyr functions such as slice_max to understand exactly how they work. Many thanks again.